# Pair of in-ear wireless headphones

Tags: headphones, wireless

I was hoping you kind people might be able to help me. I don't even know if a product such as this exists but I'm looking for two pairs of wireless in-ear headphones for me and my partner that I can connect to any 3.5mm output. Does this exist?

If I wasn't clear, I'm looking for something like this:

```
                         +---------------------+
                         |                     |
                         | In-ear Headphones 1 |
+-------------+          |                     |
|             |          +---------------------+
| Transmitter |                                  
|             |                                  
+-+-----------+          +---------------------+
  |                      |                     |
+-+---------+            | In-ear Headphones 2 |
|           |            |                     |
|           |            +---------------------+
|           |                                    
|           |                                    
|   Phone   |                                    
|           |                                    
|           |                                    
|           |                                    
|           |                                    
|           |                                    
+-----------+
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called a [Bluetooth Transmitter Splitter](https://www.google.com/search?q=bluetooth+transmitter+splitter+3.5mm) and many of them have a 3.5mm jack. It works with any kind of bluetooth audio receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pro setups that will take a 3.5mm input but a simple adapter to 1/4" would let you use any of them. You simply set the body pack (receiver) to the same frequency if you want both people to listen to the same feed. There are so many I couldn't begin to list every possibility. Here is a transmitter that will fit all of your needs minus the adapter from 3.5mm(1/8") to 1/4"
[Shure P3T-J13](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/P3T-J13)
You would also need to get body packs.
[Shure P3R-J13](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/P3RA-J13)
And then you would need to get a set of in ears. Personally I would recommend custom fit ones but there are plenty of others to choose from. And again so many that I won't attempt an exhaustive list just an example.
[Shure SE215](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/SE215)

Comment: I don't think that they ask for pro solution.

Comment: With as little detail as is provided I could say just the opposite. It is a good answer even if they weren't specifically looking for a professional solution because it would still work.